# How to solve the issue that yarn cluster manager’s apps pending count is not updated?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

I recently upgraded to emr 6.10.0 version.

I added iceberg-related settings value and yarn cluster settings reused the existing values. (It has some queue policy and min/max tasknode count policy.)

It’s not big change.

but the cluster manager’s apps pending is increasing instead of decreasing after all job is over.

so task nodes not reduce.

I can’t not find special things in the yarn log.

Is this known issue?

if anyone knows what I need to check or how to fix. please comment.